# MySql query works in mysql but leaves a field null in php

Tags: php, mysqli

I an running this query in mysql:

```
SELECT *
FROM ROOM_TYPE RT
LEFT JOIN RENT_CONTRACT RC ON RT.room_type_id = RC.room_type_id
WHERE RT.homestead_id = 20;
```

In mysql it runs perfect with the results I need. When I run it in PHP it gives me everything except for RT.room_type_id which is given back to me as null.

When I change the query to just give me that field I still get null in php. Any idea why?

```
SELECT RT.room_type_id
FROM ROOM_TYPE RT
LEFT JOIN RENT_CONTRACT RC ON RT.room_type_id = RC.room_type_id
WHERE RT.homestead_id = 20;
```

My Php, I left out the other items to just show the problem.

```
global $con;    
$qry    =   "SELECT RT.room_type_id FROM ROOM_TYPE RT LEFT JOIN RENT_CONTRACT RC ON RT.room_type_id = RC.room_type_id WHERE RT.homestead_id = 20";
$result =   mysqli_query($con,$qry);
return mysqli_fetch_assoc($result);
```

Comment: so a `var_dump()` of that returned value shows the null? Or your later `$room_type_id = $returned_data['room_type_id'];` is showing null?

Comment: If your original code on PHP is `select *` the problem is that you have two fields `room_type_id` one from RT table (which has value and the other from RC table which can be null because of left join) What is happening is that PHP is overriding this field with the one with null value. So put on your query the right fields that you want with the proper alias. Try that and let me know so I can put this as an answer.

Comment: Jorge, it looks like your answer is correct. Go ahead and submit it and I will select it. Thank you and everyone!

Comment: Before I accept your answer, can you explain why the second query is not working in php?

Answer (score 0):

Your test query:

```
SELECT RT.room_type_id
FROM ROOM_TYPE RT
LEFT JOIN RENT_CONTRACT RC ON RT.room_type_id = RC.room_type_id
WHERE RT.homestead_id = 20;
```

is equivalent to this simplified one:

```
SELECT RT.room_type_id
FROM ROOM_TYPE RT
WHERE RT.homestead_id = 20;
```

Except the origin one could have multiple occurrence of RT rows if RT->RC match is not one to one. But the distinct value set should be the same.

So for debug, maybe you can try to run the simplified query in both mysql and php and see what happens. Are you running on the same database when run through mysql and php?